# Moving average calculation

Tags: c#, performance, linq, statistics

I am hoping to make this method run a little faster. I typically need to run this on a list with more than 100000 entries. Note that at the start and end of the list, I wish to weight the average so that it is closer to the start or end value, hence the smaller framesize.

```
public PointPairList GetMovingAverage(int frameSize, PointPairList data)
{
    PointPairList movAvgPoints = new PointPairList();
    //Smooth each point in the list
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        //get the window range
        int actualFrameSize = frameSize;
        int start = i - (frameSize/2);
        int end = i + (frameSize/2);
        //ensure the window is the same size at the source list boundaries
        if (start < 0)
        {
            actualFrameSize = frameSize + start;
            start = 0;
        }
        if (end >= data.Count)
        {
            actualFrameSize = frameSize + (data.Count - 1 - end);
        }
        //Now get the sum of the window
        double sum = data.Skip(start).Take(actualFrameSize).Sum(p => p.Y);
        //add the average point to the result
        movAvgPoints.Add(new PointPair(data[i].X, sum/actualFrameSize));
    }
    return movAvgPoints;
}
```

Comment: Just a note relating to your original post: *make your titles more descriptive to what your code does*.  You can request what you would like specifically reviewed in your post.

Comment: How does your PointPairList look like? Does it implement IList<T>?

Comment: @svick Yes it does

Comment: If a`PointPairList` constructor overload can take a `capacity` parameter, you can pre-allocate the size of the list, such like `List<T>` does and score a little performance gain by constructing it with `data.Count`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Skip()` is not optimized for `IList<T>`, it always enumerates the skipped elements. This means that your algorithm is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) for no good reason. What you should do instead is to manually iterate just the required part of the input in each iteration using `for`. Something like:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < actualFrameSize; i++)
{
    sum += data[start + i].Y;
}
```

(I don't like using `GetRange()` for this, as in tinstaafl's answer, because it unnecessarily copies the frame into a new list.)

If `frameSize` is large, another optimization would be not to recompute the sum of the frame for each index. Instead, just add the item from the front and subtract the item from the back:

```
public PointPairList GetMovingAverage(int frameSize, PointPairList data)
{
    var movAvgPoints = new PointPairList();

    //Before zero
    int currentFrameSize = frameSize/2;
    double sum = data.Take(currentFrameSize).Sum(p => p.Y);

    //Smooth each point in the list
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        int removed = i - (frameSize/2) - 1;
        int added = i + (frameSize/2);

        if (removed >= 0)
        {
            sum -= data[removed].Y;
            currentFrameSize--;
        }
        if (added < data.Count)
        {
            sum += data[added].Y;
            currentFrameSize++;
        }

        movAvgPoints.Add(new PointPair(data[i].X, sum/actualFrameSize));
    }

    return movAvgPoints;
}
```

If the length of `data` is *n* and `frameSize` is *f*, then the previous algorithm would be O(*fn*), but the improved one just O(*n*).

---

Another thing: there is usually no need to create types that derive from `List`, just use `List<PointPair>` directly.

Comment: Thanks svick, good info, I will probably try to squeeze out every little bit, however the PointPairList is not my code so cannot change.